# Parse.com Javascript API Login

Tags: javascript, authentication, parse-platform

I'm trying to create a user login using Parse.com's JS SDK.  I try logging in a user I've created in the database, the page reloads and nothing happens.  I don't receive any error messages.

```
function Login()        {

<!--Connect to JS SDK-->
Parse.initialize("", "");

event.preventDefault();

//Assign form values to JS variables
var username = $("#login-username").val();
var password = $("#login-password").val();

//Log the user in
Parse.User.logIn("username", "password", {
 success: function(user) {
 alert("Welcome back, " + username)
 var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
        if(currentUser) window.location.href = 'gameslist.html';
},

error: function(user, error) {
// The login failed. Check error to see why.
}
});
}
```

My HTML form:

```
<form class="form" id="loginForm" role="form">
    <div class="inputs"> 
      <input type="text" id="login-username" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="password" id="login-password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" id="Login" value="Login" onclick="Login()"/>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Some help with this issue would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the javascript console for errors?

Comment: In Firefox: TypeError: HTMLInputElement is not a function (evaluating 'Login()')

Comment: I don't see anything specifically wrong with the code you posted, but the error message is saying that within *your* Login() function, you're trying to use a variable as a function, where the variable is actually a reference to an HTML input element. I suspect the issue is somewhere in your code that connects to the SDK (which is not posted).

Comment: Actually at a second glance, you are incorrectly putting quotation marks around "username" and "password" when calling Parse.User.logIn, however that still does not explain the error.

Comment: My SDK connection is just '<script type="text/Javascript" src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.1.min.js"></script>'

Comment: What is <!--Connect to JS SDK--> hiding? Anything to do with an input element?

Comment: The JS console should tell you the line of code that the error originated from. If you could narrow down the problematic line I'd be able to much easier help you.

Comment: Also I'd be more inclined to help if you would actually respond to my replies within a decent amount of time. On your next reply wait at least 10 minutes for me to reply. If I do, we should be able to move the discussion to chat.

Comment: Connect to JS SDK is a comment denoting the Parse.initialize.  And  "TypeError: Login is not a function login.html:1"

Comment: I see. Is this the exact code that gave you the error? Because I don't see any input elements mishandled with that code like the error says.

Comment: Also unfortunately you apparently don't have enough rep to move this to chat yet.

Comment: Removed onclick="Login()" from the submit tag and placed onsubmit="Login()" in the opening form tag

Comment: Hmmm. That doesn't explain it either. I'll keep examining your code in case I missed something. You should try running Firebug on your script. I never used it myself but I heard it's a good debugger for scripts on Firefox.

Comment: I just seen that TypeError error in the message you sent. Not the same error as last time. Did you add in a global variable named Login that is not a function? These errors do not make any sense given the code you've shown..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65714/discussion-between-jonathan-gray-and-will).

Comment: Nothing besides removing those ""'s and changing the onclick to onsubmit

Comment: You can now enter chat let's continue the discussion there

Answer (score 2):

I see a few things here:

1. You don't have any keys specified in your `initialize()` method. I assume you removed those for the sake of posting to SO, but wanted to point it out just in case.
2. In the Parse `logIn()` method, you're not passing in the `username` and `password` variables. Rather, you're passing in string literals - "username" and "password", respectively. So basically, you're telling Parse that you want to login a user named "username" who has a password of "password".
3. The reason you're not seeing any error messages is because you're not logging any to the console. You'll need to do something like the following to see what Parse is telling you is erring out:

   ```
   error: function(user, error) {
     console.log('Error Message:', error);
   }
   ```
4. Unrelated to Parse, but just another FYI, you're calling `preventDefault()` on `event` but `event` doesn't actually exist. You'll need to pass an argument into your function (in this case, called "event"), if you want to call `preventDefault()` on it.

You're definitely on the right track - keep at it!